# python django urls.py from app import views as myviews

Tags: python, django, import, django-urls

Probably I do not understand Python import correctly.

Most of the example urls.py files I find, do not have import statements for the views. Espacially in combination with contrib packages like rosetta or scribbler.

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from forum import urls as forum_urls

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'home.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^rosetta/', include('rosetta.urls')),
    url(r'^forum/', include(forum_urls)),
)
```

Why can't I also include forum.urls without an include statement?

While experimenting I found something interesting. when I start ipython using ./manage.py shell, and than import forum; I can type forum.[tab] to get tab-completion and ipython gives me models als completion, but not views. My

```
__init__.py
```

file is empty and I have a simple models.py as I have a simple views.py.

So, how come the two mudules behave different?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of rosetta and scribbler, they're added to the INSTALLED_APPS section of the settings.py file, so that's probably how they're getting imported.

Comment: The forum is also one of the installed apps, so this can't be the difference.